# How to fix "unreachable code detected" error?

Tags: c#

I written a server program for  multiple client connection and I got above error in one method . I tried some options like "#pragma warning disable " but it doesn't works. Please give me suggestions to fix this. Error is at bold line just after the while loop and if I remove "clientSocket.close()" and "serverSocket.Stop()"  error not showing, but i need to write these statements here.
Thanks !

here is my code,

```
  public void startServer()
  {
     int port = Convert.ToInt32(txtport.Text);
     string ipaddre = getip();
     IPAddress iP = IPAddress.Parse(ipaddre);
     TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(iP, port);
     TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
     int counter = 0;
     serverSocket.Start();
     AppendTxtdata("Server Started , Waiting for Client Connection");
     counter = 0;
    #pragma warning disable

     while (true)
     {
            counter += 1;
           clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
           AppendTxtdata(" >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " Connected-- IP -                "+clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()+"");
           AppendTxtdata(Environment.NewLine);
           handleClient client = new connectSuccess.handleClient();
           client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter));
     }
      **AppendTxtdata("Data sent to Client No :" + Convert.ToString(counter));**
     clientSocket.Close();
     serverSocket.Stop();
     AppendTxtdata(" >> " + "exit");
     #pragma warning restore
 }
```

Comment: while(true) will create an infinite loop, i don't see any break in the while block, that's why the code is unreachable.

Comment: I would probably try to avoid `#pragma warning disable` as well.  Warnings are generally trying to help you and should not be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having an infinite loop, you could add a condition variable so that you can control when the  while loop should break. It is only when your loop breaks that the code below the loop gets reached.

Below is an example of how you could add a condition variable to your code and how you can utilize this to control the state of your server.

```
private bool IsRunning = false;

public void StartServer()
{
    int port = Convert.ToInt32(txtport.Text);
    string ipaddre = getip();
    IPAddress iP = IPAddress.Parse(ipaddre);
    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(iP, port);
    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    int counter = 0;
    serverSocket.Start();
    AppendTxtdata("Server Started , Waiting for Client Connection");
    counter = 0;

    IsRunning = true;

    while (IsRunning)
    {
        counter += 1;
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        AppendTxtdata(" >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " Connected" + clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()+"");
        AppendTxtdata(Environment.NewLine);
        handleClient client = new connectSuccess.handleClient();
        client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter));
     }
      **AppendTxtdata("Data sent to Client No :" + Convert.ToString(counter));**
     clientSocket.Close();
     serverSocket.Stop();
     AppendTxtdata(" >> " + "exit");
 }

public void StopServer()
{
    IsRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: this condition works . but I tried with 3030 port befor posting this query, and still it gives problem with this port. can you tell me why this error gives on 3030 port.

Comment: @PriyankaBarwad That would be hard to tell without more information. Are your client and server on the same LAN, or do they communicate over WAN? It could have something to do with your router configuration. Also make sure that the client is dialing the same port as the server is listening at.

Comment: yes server and client are on same LAN and client dialing same port . I set time from  minutes to 30 seconds. but this is not applied.

Answer (score 11):

Your `while` loop never breaks so the code afterwards semantically won't be reached. Break the loop somehow: either manually with `break` or conditionally with `while(someConditionThatChangesInFuture)`.

The warning comes from the fact the compiler or another tool (such as ReSharper) has analysed the code and cannot find a possible way out of the loop.

It also sounds like you treat warnings as errors. If so, I would speak to your peers about this, asking for a code review. Disabling warnings is not something to be done lightly.

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix the warning is to fix your code, not to try and hide the problem. You have a `while` loop that never exits:

```
while (true)
{
    //true will always be true and there's no break
}
// Code here can never be reached.
```

So either remove the unreachable code, or fix the loop so it ends in some way.